# ¿Cuál es el nombre en castellano del eje z?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

Cuando trabajamos en dos dimensiones (2D) utilizamos los ejes **x** horizontal e **y** vertical.

Al trabajar en tres dimensiones (3D) utilizamos los ejes **x** horizontal, **y** vertical y **z**. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo se llama en castellano el eje **z**?

Contexto: En CSS hay una función, translate3d(), utilizada para trasladar un elemento en 3D a lo largo de los ejes *x, y, z*.

Comment: Yo tiendo a pensar en el plano horizontal (el definido por los ejes _x_ e _y_) y el eje vertical (el eje _z_). También puedes pensar en los ejes como los que definen el largo, ancho y alto. Otra opción es pensar en el eje _z_ como el eje de profundidad, si los ejes _x_ e _y_ te definen el plano de lo que ves, como la imagen que ves en un monitor. También puedes pensar en los ejes como _abscisas_, _ordenadas_ y ¿cuál sería el _z_? Tal vez si nos dices cuál es tu contexto específico esta pregunta pueda tener un poco más de sentido, ahora mismo la veo un poco vaga.

Comment: Uno de *anchura, altura, profundidad*? Dependiendo de cuales ya has llamado los ejes **x** e **y**.

Comment: @Charlie @ukemi gracias por sus comentarios. _Profundidad_ es una buena palabra. El contexto específico de esta pregunta: en CSS hay algunas funciones como por ejemplo `translate3d()` utilizada para trasladar un elemento en 3D a lo largo de los ejes x,y, z

Comment: [This exact same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56472/280768) on ELU.

Comment: Gracias por darnos el contexto.  Ahora, si eres tan amble, danos también una frase, indicando el lugar donde vendría el término que buscas con un guión ( _________ ).

Comment: En stackoverflow SE ví que en el contexto de CSS a veces usan *shadow (sombra)* o *perspective (perspectiva)* para la tercera dimensión.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Creo que voy a utilizar _profundidad_. Vea los comentarios arriba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Al trabajar en tres dimensiones (3D) utilizamos los ejes `x` horizontal, `y` vertical y `z`.

Bueno, esto en realidad no es así. En un espacio tridimensional (o espacio euclídeo, más bien), la convención es que los ejes para `X` e `Y` se pinten ambos de manera que el plano `XY` sea un plano horizontal, y es el eje para `Z` el que se pinta vertical:

[image]

Es cierto que a veces se pintan como si fuera un plano 2D (`X` horizontal, `Y` vertical) al que se le ha añadido un eje `Z` para darle "profundidad":

[image]

Pero no es lo más correcto.

Sobre el nombre del eje: en muchos textos en español, para `X`, `Y` y `Z` se usan los nombres [abscisa, ordenada y **cota**](https://www.google.com/search?q=abscisa%20ordenada%20y%20cota), respectivamente; por tanto al eje `Z` se le llama **eje de cotas**.

Comment: yo las conocia como alto, largo y ancho

Comment: ¿Se puede usar *normal* para *z* también?

Comment: Nunca en mi vida he visto o oído la expresión "eje de cotas" para llamar al "eje de las *z*".

Answer (score 3):

En cada disciplina se puede usar un criterio diferente respecto a la orientación de los tres ejes. En consecuencia, cada eje puede recibir nombres muy variados. Al contrario de lo que se indica en otra respuesta, no hay criterios más correctos que otros (salvo imponer que el sistema sea dextrógiro, pero eso es para otro foro).

Es común disponer los ejes X e Y horizontalmente, usando Z para a la altura. Pero incluso usando una misma disposición, los ejes pueden recibir nombres diferentes. Por ejemplo, en topografía, las coordenadas cartesianas se denominan *coordenada Este* (*Easting* en ingles), *coordenada Norte* (*Northing*) y *elevación*.

Olvidándonos incluso de cuál es X, Y o Z, en anatomía se denominan *longitudinal* (de arriba a abajo) *transversal* (de izquierda a derecha) y *sagital* (de delante hacia atrás). Y en aeronáutica se denominan ejes de *cabeceo* (*pitch*), *alabeo* (*roll*) y *guiñada* (*yaw*).

Y así podemos seguir...

Pero la pregunta se refiere específicamente a CSS. En CSS se usa el [modelo de cámara](https://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transforms/demo-rotate3d.html) donde X representa la dimensión horizontal del monitor, Y representa la dimensión vertical del monitor, y Z representa la orientación de la línea de visión. En este sentido, "anchura", "altura" y "profundidad", respectivamente, son nombres adecuados.

[image: CSS axes]

Aunque, para complicar las cosas, el valor de altura crece hacia abajo (¿¿¿*bajura*???).

Comment: ¿crece hacia arriba? (=altura); ¿hacia abajo?=hondura)